# HTML mails and display property

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've just tested some HTML email examples on how they are displayed in diffirent e-mails viewers / programs. I noticed that the css property "display" is removed (basically in Gmail) and some web-interfaces ask for approval to use it?!

I don't really think there's a workaround for this but I also can't believe that such important thing could be removed and left out like this without a possibility to use it.

Maybe someone has an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: welcome to html emails, friend. :)  Here's a useful link! http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @JosephMarikle that's weird, I just tried several `display` properties which that list claims won't work on Gmail while it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes, I already googled out the link you provided and as I said - I already know about this html email disfunctionalities. What I'm asking if there's maybe some hacks or workarounds or maybe even some e-mail-provider specific functionalities for such things?

Comment: @Marcel, can you give an example? I'm pretty sure it's not working (just tested again with only a div with diffirent display types).

Comment: @TaruoGene I just did a quick test on a password reset mail I convienently had open, added a `display:none` and a `display:block` on 2 elements and both behaved like html would. Tested using Gmail directly and Gmail trough Windows Live Mail. Though .. I guess you want to be certain, so I'd stick to the list, it would also be hard to test your work if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Marcel I'm sure that list is as close to current as you can get with HTML emails.  Here's a test case: open http://jsfiddle.net/BJv22/show/ in safari and choose the option `File->Mail Contents of This Page (may be different in Windows)` and send it to your gmail.  Open it in gmail and you'll see the hidden text.  You can of course add it via developer tools and it might work in a desktop client, but for gmail itself, it gets parsed out.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yeah, it's quite up-to-date, the updates are listed at the bottom. The mail only shows 'hallo there', not sure why it works for me, but I won't complain.